# Pytorch's `binary_cross_entropy` seems to implement ln(0) = -100. Why?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, cross-entropy, natural-logarithm

I'm curious as to why Pytorch's `binary_cross_entropy` function seems to be implemented in such a way to calculate ln(0) = -100.

The binary cross entropy function from a math point of view calculates:

H = -[ p_0*log(q_0) + p_1*log(q_1) ]

In pytorch's `binary_cross_entropy` function, `q` is the first argument and `p` is the second.

Now suppose I do `p = [1,0]` and `q = [0.25, 0.75]`. In this case, `F.binary_cross_entropy(q,p)` returns, as expected: -ln(0.25) = 1.386.

If we reverse the function arguments and try `F.binary_cross_entropy(p,q)`, this should return an error, since we would try calculating -0.75*ln(0), and ln(0) is in the limit -infinity.

Nonetheless, if I do `F.binary_cross_entropy(p,q)` it gives me 75 as the answer (see below):

```
> import torch.nn.functional as F 
> pT = torch.Tensor([1,0]) 
> qT =torch.Tensor([0.25,0.75]) 
> F.binary_cross_entropy(pT,qT)
```

> tensor(75.)

Why it was implemented in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed filling the value with -100. You can find an example of that [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/4b74bb6c3428c111bf0c823aa6db1fa58fcf82c2/aten/src/ATen/native/Loss.cpp#L292).

This is most likely a hack to avoid an error caused by accidental rounding to zero.

Technically speaking, the input probabilities to `binary_cross_entropy` are supposed to be generated by a sigmoid function, which is bounded asymptotically between `(0, 1)`. This means the input should never actually be zero, but this may occur due to numerical precision issues for very small values.